# How to get Hadoop configuration xml info using rest api

Tags: hadoop, configuration

I have `core-site.xml`, `mapred-site.xml`, `hdfs-site.xml` and `yarn-site.xml` file at '$(hadoop_home)\etc\hadoop'.

I need to get those xml files using weblink or webHdfs rest command.

In following link I able to get `core-site.xml`, `mapred-site.xml` using jmx (or) rest command.

*http://<host-name>:8088/conf*

How to get `core-site.xml` and `yarn-site.xml` property also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got a solution for getting hadoop configuration information using rest or jmx command.

**Namenode Configuration:**

http://<host-name>:50070/conf -> (core-site.xml, mapred-site.xml, yarn-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml)

**Node manager Configuration:**

http://<host-name>:8042/conf -> (core-site.xml, mapred-site.xml, yarn-site.xml)

**Resource manager Configuration:**

http://<host-name>:8088/conf -> (core-site.xml, mapred-site.xml)

*Note:* Make sure datanode and nodeManager information have to check with slave node. And namnode and resourceManager information have to check with master node